# Create a standalone form shortcut in Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: html, forms, ms-access-2013

I currently have a functioning form that searches through my database by calling a query. What I'm trying to do is turn this into a standalone application where I can simply open a file and only the form opens, running the database on the back-end. I have tried running a macro that opens the form, and I have tried creating a shortcut to my desktop, but nothing has worked.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Anything that will only show the form and the search results would be good (desktop shortcut, HTML file, etc.).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split your database so that the tables are located in a separate back-end file (which can be kept on a server). [These instructions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx) apply to Access 2007 and 2010 but the process is very similar for 2013.

Once this is done, your tables will become linked tables (stored in a separate file) and your front-end .addcb file will only contain queries, forms and reports.

You can control which form opens when the application loads through File -> Options -> Current Database. There are also several other useful controls here for limiting what the user can do; ie.

- Hiding the list of database
- Hiding the tabs (you will therefore need to create buttons to move between forms)
- Hiding the Ribbon and/or status bar
- Disabling Layout View

It's safest to change these settings on a copy, so you don't inadvertently lock yourself out; however, by holding down shift when opening the file from within Access, most of these options will be bypassed and you will be able to edit the database / revert these settings should you need to.

In terms of making it a "stand-alone application", it is possible to create a copy that will open without requiring the full version of MS Access on the user's PC (instead using Access Runtime).

I always distribute my front-ends as .accde format (File -> Export ACCDE). The benefits are as follows:

- Smaller file size
- Optimise memory usage / improves performance
- VBA code runs but cannot be viewed or edited

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/command-line-switches-for-access-HA010166605.aspx

and

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/command-function-HA001228801.aspx

Basic idea, create a macro called **AutoExec** that checks for a command line argument when opening the database. Setup a shortcut with a command line argument (whatever you decide to name it, I'll use 'lookuponly' as the example.) like this:

```
"C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\MyDatabase.mdb" /cmd "lookuponly"
```

when you double click the shortcut it should auto-run the macro and open your lookup form. Of course under newer versions of access you'll have to set the location of the database as a trusted location or access will attempt to block the database.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/decide-whether-to-trust-a-database-HA010256412.aspx

Comment: I tried the tips from those sites, but I wasn't able to apply them to Access 2013 and I'm not using VBA. Do you know of any other ways to run the Access form without booting up Access first?